# AWS Cognito admin_get_user performance on large(r) scale

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have to implement a [Pre Token Generation Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html) in order to add custom attributes into the Access Token. The custom attribute/value is stored in the user settings of each user within the Cognito User Pool and I can retrieve it with the boto3 [admin_get_user](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.admin_get_user) function.

The question I have is whether it is a good idea to call the admin_get_user (or any other function that loads data from Cognito) from a performance point of view. Does Cognito internally scales and handles a burst of requests well? Or is it better to retrieve the custom attributes from a different place because Cognito is perhaps not meant to be used for such lookups?

My Lambda will be executed on every successful authentication and more importantly, on every token refresh which happens every 60min (given that ever issued access token expires after max 60min)

Comment: I don't think you would face performance issues with the API calls as the Cognito API calls request data from Amazon's internal APIs. 
However, you should keep in mind that API calls have their own limits, and you might have to contact AWS Support to increase the limit for the admin-get-user call.

Comment: @lightyagami Yes, I was expecting the function to use the internal API of Cognito. But what do you mean with "their own limits"? Do you mean max. calls per hour/day etc? Where do I find this information?
I found it in general hard to get support for Cognito. I dont think they (AWS) are active on the AWS Forums...

Comment: Kindly refer to this following documentation for more information about API call [limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html).

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is old. I recently faced the same issue. So just adding an answer to help others.

the AdminGetUser documented quota/limit is 5 requests per min. You can request AWS to increase the limit. or You can configure the aws client, you are using to have a back off strategy and retry configuration.

you can find limit or quota for api calls here : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html

An interesting article on how the backOff strategy work & which one to choose: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/exponential-backoff-and-jitter/

I would recommend https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/retry/PredefinedBackoffStrategies.FullJitterBackoffStrategy.html

For more info read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html